# Debugging Tests in VS2008 Slow due to loading symbols

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, debugging

If I click on 'debug all tests' in Visual Studio 2008 it takes ages to start (whereas 'run all tests' starts instantly). As far a can tell, this is because it is downloading symbols from Microsoft. Why is this? Is there anyway I can stop it or to make it start faster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols` and check the box for "Search the above locations only when symbols are loaded manually."

It won't affect breakpoints or anything; the only thing it means is when you see a callstack without symbols you have to right click the frame in the callstack and "Load Symbols > From Symbol Path".

Comment: To make sure the setting is applied, make sure no other copies of Visual Studio were open when you set it. Then exit and restart Visual Studio to make sure the setting is saved. If you did that and it's still slow, then it's definitely not due to downloading symbols. :)

Comment: Ah, I assumed the setting would be applied instantly. That sorted it, thanks.

Comment: This setting doesn't seem to exist in VS2010. Any ideas as to what is now required?

Comment: I have the same problem in VS2012 and I cannot resolve it. All Symbol related settings in VS are switched off. Any idea?

Comment: @DavidRoth On VS2012 Premium, I fixed this by going to Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols, and checking "Only specified modules". Save, restart all VS's, and it went from ~20 secs to start to debug a test to <1.

Comment: Worked for me. Went from a several second pause stepping between lines of code in instantaneous